# Fast PDF printer software to print 2 pages per sheet

Tags: windows, pdf

I'd like to print a PDF (260 pages) in a new PDF with 2 pages per sheet (130 pages). My OS: Win 8.1.

Before I've used https://online2pdf.com/de/ and **PDF24 Creator**, but it takes 5 min for approximately 10 pages to convert.

Do you know a very very fast PDF printer alternative (freeware, without markup preferred)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Foxit PDF Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/) is, in my experience, a faster and more lightweight solution than Adobe's suite for managing PDF files.

Installing the free **Foxit PDF Reader** also, by default, installs the [Foxit Reader PDF Printer](https://youtu.be/c_YGdWtaHsM?t=116), which can save any printable output to a PDF file -- including output from the Foxit Reader itself. You can use this to create a 130 page PDF, as follows:

1. Open your document in **Foxit Reader**
2. Press **Control-P** to bring up the print document dialog.
3. Under the "**Name:**" field, choose "**Foxit Reader PDF Printer**" as the printer.
4. *Optional:* Click the "**Properties**" button to configure the printer's options to do tweaks to speed up the generation of the resultant PDF, at the cost of quality.

   1. Choose "**Standard**" under the **Default Settings**, and click the "**Edit**" button.
   2. Modify all "**Downsampling**" options to "**Average Downsampling**."
   3. Click "**OK**." Foxit will prompt you to save the settings, name it something like "**Fast and Low Quality**."
   4. Under **Image Resolution:** choose "**144**".
   5. Click **OK**.
5. *Optional:* to remove any markups (annotations) that you have made (as described in your requirements), select "**Document**" under the **Print what:** drop down box. The default is to print "Document and markups."
6. Under the **Print Handling** section, press the "**Multiple Pages Per Sheet**" button. Immediately below that, select **2 pages per sheet**.
7. Make sure that "**Auto-rotate**" and "**Auto-center**" are both checked to ensure that the pages are rendered properly.
8. Click **OK**. Foxit Reader PDF Printer will prompt you to specify where you would like your new PDF file saved.

In my testing, I was able to reformat an image-heavy **400 page PDF** into a 200 page PDF in **2 minutes** on a 2.8GHz E7400 dual-core system. Quality suffers a bit. Disabling compression entirely increases quality and results in a seven-minute conversion time.